# summarizing a list of character vectors using forcats and purrr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr, forcats

I have tibble where `col1` is a list of character vectors of variable length and `col2` is a numeric vector indicating a group assignment, either 1 or 0. I want to first convert all of the character vectors in the list (`col1`) to factors, and then unify all of the factors levels across these factors so that I can ultimately get a tally of counts for each factor level.  For the example data below, that would mean the tally would be as follows:

overall:

```
    level, count  
    "a", 2
    "b", 2
    "c", 2
    "d", 3
    "e", 1
```

for group=1:

```
    level, count  
    "a", 1
    "b", 2
    "c", 1
    "d", 1
    "e", 0
```

for group=0:

```
    level, count  
    "a", 1
    "b", 0
    "c", 1
    "d", 2
    "e", 1
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to get a total count of each factor level `c("a","b","c","d","e")` and plot them by the grouping variable.

Here is some code that might give better context to my problem:

```
library(forcats)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tib <- tibble(col1=list(c("a","b"),
                 c("b","c","d"), 
                 c("a","d","e"),
                 c("c","d")),
       col2=c(1,1,0,0))


tib %>% 
  mutate(col3=map(.$col1,.f = as_factor)) %>% 
  mutate(col4=map(.$col3,.f = fct_unify))
```

Unfortunately, this code fails.  I get the following error, but don't know why:

`Error:`fs`must be a list`

I thought my input was a list?

I appreciate any help anyone might offer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `unnest` and then `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tib %>%
  unnest(col = col1) %>%
  #If needed col1 as factors
  #mutate(col1 =factor(col1)) %>%
  count(col1)

#  col1      n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 a         2
#2 b         2
#3 c         2
#4 d         3
#5 e         1
```

---

To `count` based on group i.e `col2`, we can do

```
tib %>% 
  unnest(col = col1) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(col1, col2), factor) %>%
  count(col1, col2, .drop = FALSE)

#   col1  col2      n
#   <fct> <fct> <int>
# 1 a     0         1
# 2 a     1         1
# 3 b     0         0
# 4 b     1         2
# 5 c     0         1
# 6 c     1         1
# 7 d     0         2
# 8 d     1         1
# 9 e     0         1
#10 e     1         0
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ronak Shah. I suppose I wanted to unify the factor levels so that I could more easily compare plots -- in the grouping example you provided, it looks like factor levels with 0 counts do not show up. level "b" for group=0 should have n=0; likewise; level "e" for group = 1 should have n=0.

Comment: @HumanityFirst okay, updated the answer. Now it shows factors with count 0 as well.

Comment: Wow that's such a nice solution to my problem -- thanks!